# I infiltrated a cult, but now I think I want to join them. Should I?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Minor spoilers for a quest on Dromund Kaas...

So I was hired to join the Revanites and unmask their leader. I finally met the leader and she knows why I joined and has proposed I lie to the guy who hired me.

Can anyone tell me what happens if I betray the cult? Betray my original employer?

Comment: I love the question title

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's really no difference other than the alignment points, and possibly companion affection.

Either way, you'll gain the 'Revanite' title, the same XP and item rewards, and after a little while, a letter with some credits from whoever you sided with.

There's no lasting impact, though this isn't the last of Revan's legacy with which you'll interact.

Comment: Which I think is a shame. Almost none of the of the decisions you make have a lasting impact.

Comment: Some decisions do, but only within your class quest. The biggest example is in the Sith Warrior class quest with Jaesa Willsam.

Comment: @atreusmonk that's far from the only example, or possibly even the biggest. But I'm not going to spoil the Imperial Agent storyline just to prove a point.